# Finding a formula for a recursively defined sequence and proving it

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to find a non-recursive formula for a sequence defined as:

$F_{0} = 3$

$\forall n\in \mathbb N, \, n>0: \, F_{n} = F_{0}F_{1}...F_{n-1}+2$

Also I need to prove the formula by induction but that shouldn't be a problem. 
I'm having problem with finding this formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Have a look at $F_n - 1$ for the first few n. Maybe you recognise those numbers.

Answer (score 2):

$F_0=3$ and for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$: $$F_n=F_0F_1...F_{n-1}+2$$
$$F_n=F_0F_1...F_{n-2}F_{n-1}+2=(F_{n-1}-2)F_{n-1}+2=(F_{n-1}-1)^2+1$$
this would imply 
$$F_{n}-1=(F_{n-1}-1)^2$$
Define $G_{n}=F_n-1$ the rewrite the above problem as
$$G_n=G^2_{n-1}$$ with $G_0=2$. Now you can see that 
$$G_n=2^{2^n}$$
or in terms of $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$.